# turn off mouse LEDs

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, mouse

I have a Logitech 910-004845 G203 Gaming Mouse

I want to turn off its LEDs all the time

I tried  installing logitech gaming software, couldn't see a way to do it

So how can I do it?

I know it's possible, the LEDs turn off when the laptop sleeps

Comment: Do you even have your mouse shown in the device list? When I plug mine in, it shows a G102 (which is not even the device I plugued in), which disappear when I disconnect it. However, it shows it as "Disconnected" and I do not have access to any option for the device 

Answer (score 1):

Only way to do it is through the software. Choose your mouse in the bottom left corner of the Logitech Gaming Software, and click on the colored lightbulb-- that is the light settings. Then there is an option to toggle off the LEDs.

Comment: probably this is not the only way to do it,